# Python/Pandas -- Converting row number to hour and then slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I've read into Python with Pandas that is as follows:

`>>> df
            id       temp
0            1  272.53702
1            2  272.41101
2            3  272.18503
3            4  271.79102
4            5  271.33701
5            6  270.86200
6            7  270.41501
7            8  269.97501
8            9  269.56201
9           10  269.18802
...`

The `id` field represents every hour from the first hour of 1989 (midnight January 1st, 1989) to the last hour of 2010. My goal is to extract a list from the `temp` column representing temperatures from May 1st, 2002, to November 20th, 2006, and then to fit the list using Scipy's spline interpolation. My question -- what is the most efficient way of converting `id` to datetime, and then slicing to get the appropriate date range I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create a `datetime` column from `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic to determine which `id` values correspond to the start and end dates you're looking for, and then use `loc` to select the associated temperatures.  This will likely be faster than converting all of the `id` values to dates, then slicing.

```
start = 24*(pd.to_datetime('2002-05-01') - pd.to_datetime('1989-01-01')).days
end = 24*(pd.to_datetime('2006-11-20') - pd.to_datetime('1989-01-01')).days - 1
temp_values = df.loc[df['id'].between(start, end), 'temp'].values
```

By "to November 20th, 2006", I'm assuming you mean up to but not including November 20th, 2006.  If you want data *through* the 20th, just use the 21st instead of the 20th in the computation of `end`. I'm subtracting one from `end` to get the last hour of the day prior to the date in the computation, as to not include the date used in the computation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've noticed that the length of `temp_values` is 1 longer than the number of rows I have after slicing `df` with `df[start:end]`. Why is that?

Comment: `df[start:end]` uses python's slice notation, which does not include `end`.  For `temp_values`, I'm using pandas' `.between`, which does include `end`.  Based on how I computed `end`, you want to include it.

Comment: Actually, `start` was not included. The 'end' terms were in both the sliced `df` and `temp_values`. Doing `df[start-1:end]` matched with `temp_values`.

Comment: Oh, yes, that would be because slice notation starts at 0, but the `id` value starts at 1.  That would shift things forward by one, so `start` would not be included but `end` would, like you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's basically what you need to use:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> print datetime(1989, 1, 1)
1989-01-01 00:00:00
>>> print datetime(1989, 1, 1) + timedelta(hours=5)
1989-01-01 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just adding a `datetime` column which will allow you to pass `datetime` objects for selection:

```
In [162]:
df['date'] = dt.datetime(1989,1,1) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['id'], 'h')
df

Out[162]:
   id       temp                date
0   1  272.53702 1989-01-01 01:00:00
1   2  272.41101 1989-01-01 02:00:00
2   3  272.18503 1989-01-01 03:00:00
3   4  271.79102 1989-01-01 04:00:00
4   5  271.33701 1989-01-01 05:00:00
5   6  270.86200 1989-01-01 06:00:00
6   7  270.41501 1989-01-01 07:00:00
7   8  269.97501 1989-01-01 08:00:00
8   9  269.56201 1989-01-01 09:00:00
9  10  269.18802 1989-01-01 10:00:00

In [163]:
df.loc[df['date'] > '1989-01-01 06:00']

Out[163]:
   id       temp                date
6   7  270.41501 1989-01-01 07:00:00
7   8  269.97501 1989-01-01 08:00:00
8   9  269.56201 1989-01-01 09:00:00
9  10  269.18802 1989-01-01 10:00:00
```